# Equation of a plane containing 2 points

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find the equation of the plane containing the vectors $(1, 0, \sqrt{3})$ and $(1, \sqrt{3}, 0)$. The vectors are in standard position.

I first get the vector between the 2 points
$\vec{v}^{\ } = (1, 0, \sqrt{3}) - (1, \sqrt{3}, 0) = (0, -\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3})$

Next I determine part of the equation by taking the norm and the dot product of the vector I calculated.

$(x, y, z).(0, -\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3}) = 0\ -\sqrt{3}y + \sqrt{3}z = 0$

Next I calculate d by plugging one of my original points

$ -\sqrt{3}(0) + \sqrt{3}(\sqrt{3}) = d = 3 $

which gives me this equation

$ -\sqrt{3}y + \sqrt{3}z = 3 $

But I know this is wrong, because when I plug $(1, 0, \sqrt{3})$ into the equation it makes no sense.

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: "The plane?" Unless you mean the plane through the original, there are a lot of such planes.

Comment: hmm... unfortunately the question only says the plane containing the vectors

Comment: Quite often, when talking about "vectors" rather than "points," looking for planes containing vectors means including the origin. But that is highly dependent on the context.

Comment: That does make sense, since they did implicitly state that the vectors are in standard position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have two vectors, remember that the plane equation requires a normal vector. This normal vector should be perpendicular to both vectors, which means you should take the cross product of the two vectors you were given. The result is your normal vector.

Comment: it also makes sense in the context, since 2 question before this one they ask you to calculate the cross product